# How to check that an uploaded file is a valid Image in Django

Tags: django

I have an ImageField in one of my models so that users can upload an image. When a user submits an upload form, I want to verify that the file in question is a fully valid and displayable image.

I tried using PIL to verify that the image was in fact authentic, but using

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open(model.file)
Image.verify()
```

No matter what file I give it though, it always throws an exception.

Anyone know of an easy way to verify the file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good news, you don't need to do this:

> class ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, **options)
>
> Inherits all attributes and methods from FileField, but also validates that the uploaded object is a valid image.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField

Comment: This is correct, but it appears it doesn't do this all by itself. It requires that you setup the form in forms.py in order for the validation to occur.

Comment: Were you handling the upload by processing the raw post data?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to handle it all in the views method that I had setup. I set it up with a forms system as well as the is_valid() method and that worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it works. Django forms is definitely the way to go

Comment: @Zach Sugano can you provide source that ImageField validation only works with Django forms? Would be very helpful. I'd need image validation, but Django is only a backend, so can't use their forms.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you should use verify() as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(model.file)
im.verify()
```

Comment: I thinks pillow will raise exception when open image instead of need to verify after image opened. So, secondth line will raise `IOError` if image is not valid.

Comment: This is what Django's `ImageField` does already. See the source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2ea3fb3e6386c43f124b542e92b817dbc227c76b/django/forms/fields.py#L634

Answer (score 2):

you can use a 'Pillow' with 'try,except 'block, before insert image/data to a database or use it where you want,

like my following example for submit ticket support form , 'view.py' file :

```
from PIL import Image
    
    if request.method=='POST':
       # check if attachment file is not empty inside try/except to pass django error.
        try:
            ticket_attachmet_image = request.FILES["q_attachment_image"]
        except:
            ticket_attachmet_image = None

       # check if uploaded image is valid (for example not video file ) .
        if not ticket_attachmet_image == None:
            try:
                Image.open(ticket_attachmet_image)
            except:
                messages.warning(request, 'sorry, your image is invalid')
                return redirect('your_url_name')
```

#done.

Comment: here you have posted code from a function without showing the function. People using a class based view will not understand how this could possibly be implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'image' in request.FILES['image'].content_type:
    # Some code
else:
    # the file is not image
```

The `ImageField` doesn't work when the form is not created by the `form.py`

In fact, if we upload a file, that is not an image, and save it in the image field, it wouldn't raise any error so, the `content_type` of the file must be checked before saving.

Comment: `content_type` can be manipulated; you're effectively trusting users to send the correct content type which is insecure. Files must be independently verified they are the correct file type. From the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.content_type

Comment: is this "request.FILES" exclusively for a function-based view? the documentation loves to omit details like this

Comment: FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the <form> that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data", So in class-based views it contains data in POST method or, in function-based views if the request.method is 'POST'. @Conor

Comment: thanks yes I figured out about those CreateView functions just yesterday (new to Django)